# Uncaught TypeError: this.method is not a function - Node js class export

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, rollup

I am new to node.js and I am trying to require a class. I have used https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes as reference. However, when I do this for example:

```
// talker.js
class Talker {
    talk(msg) {
        console.log(this.say(msg))
        var t = setTimeout(this.talk, 5000, 'hello again');
    }
    say(msg) {
        return msg
    }
}
export default Talker

// app.js
import Talker from './taker.js'
const talker = new Talker()
talker.talk('hello')
```

I get:

> talker.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: this.say is not a function

It should be said that app.js is the electron.js renderer process and it bundled using rollup.js

Any ideas why this would be?

**Update:** Sorry, I forgot to add in a line when putting in the psuedo code. It actually happens when I call `setTimeout` with callback. I have updated the code.

Comment: What does `console.log(this)` show in `talk()`?

Comment: ```Talker {}
__proto__
:
Object```

Comment: Running the code in a single file without the export and import lines works fine.

Comment: Apologies, I left out a vital line of code when pasting in the example. I have put an update in the question.

Comment: Yes, that was a bit vital =D For what it’s worth, I’d use `() => this.talk('hello again')` instead of `this.talk.bind(this)`.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, yes, that works too, why would that be better?

Comment: @CUGreen: `bind` is slow, duplicates its context (here, you have to write `this` twice, for example), and adds confusion in some cases as to how many arguments are going to be passed to the function (because it adds any arguments it gets and some places that accept callbacks call them with an unexpected number of arguments). Best to be explicit. The arrow function is also shorter.

Comment: great, thanks @Ryan, makes sense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are losing the bind of `this` to your method.

Change from this:

```
setTimeout(this.talk, 5000, 'hello again');
```

to this:

```
setTimeout(this.talk.bind(this), 5000, 'hello again');
```

---

When you pass `this.talk` as a function argument, it takes `this` and looks up the method `talk` and passes a reference to that function.  But, it only passes a reference to that function.  There is no longer any association with the object you had in `this`.  `.bind()` allows you to pass a reference to a tiny stub function that will keep track of `this` and call your method as `this.say()`, not just as `say()`.

You can see the same thing if you just did this:

```
const talker = new Talker();'

const fn = talker.say;
fn();
```

This would generate the same issue because assigning the method to `fn` takes no associate to `talker` with it at all.  It's just a function reference without any association with an object.  In fact:

```
talker.say === Talker.prototype.say
```

What `.bind()` does is create a small stub function that will save the object value and will then call your method using that object.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you :-)